# I can´t use alias in sql delete

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

I tried execute this sql sentence

```
delete 
        from reclamo r
        where exists ( select 1 from reclamo r
                        join cliente c on r.cod_cliente = c.cod_cliente
                        join localidad l on c.cod_localidad = l.cod_localidad
                        where l.descripcion = 'San Justo');
```

for remove all the claims made by customers of the town of 'San justo'
but it says "Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'r
        where exists ( select 1 from reclamo r
                        join cliente c on r.cod_cliente' at line 2"
 anyone know how I can fix these errors?

sqlfiddele here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b2771

Comment: Your sqfiddle is incomplete btw (probably because of the ddl char limit).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using aliases... ÿou have to tell what to actually delete (probably this is because table aliases are usually only *needed* in multiple table syntax... you could just omit the alias altogether):

```
mysql> delete from tablename r;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'r' at line 1
mysql> delete r from tablename r;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

See als [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/delete.html):

> Note
>    If you declare an alias for a table, you must use the alias when referring to the table: 
>   DELETE t1 FROM test AS t1, test2 WHERE ...

Comment: and you can't use LIMIT

Answer (score 1):

Don't use an alias.  This is equivalent logic and will work fine.

```
delete from reclamo
where cod_cliente in 
(select cod_cliente
from cliente c join localidad l on c.cod_localidad = l.cod_localidad
where l.descripcion = 'San Justo');
```